# Replace values in 2D arrays with bin numbers (down sample)

Tags: histograms, list-manipulation

I have a 2D array with a lot of large values in it. This is the histogram for the data with the values grouped into 16 different bins:

[image]

I want to replace all the values in the array with their bin number so that each value in the array is just one of 16 possible values (0-15). How can I do that?

Comment: What does "2D" have to do with anything here?  What does "down sample" have to do with anything here?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The values in this case are frequencies. When frequencies are binned in this way it is sometimes referred to as "downsampling". Since my data is in a 2D array, ie list of lists, (notice the Flatten function above), I need a solution that operates on a list of lists.

Comment: Have you tried [`ArrayResample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayResample.html)?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice image processing function you can exploit to quantize your data. Say the array is called `data` (for demonstration, make it up from random numbers). Then `quan` quantizes this to only n=3 values (you can do any number, like 16). The Tally shows that you have indeed only n values in the quantized array.

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 100}];
quan = ImageData[ColorQuantize[Image[data], 3]]; 
tal = Tally[Flatten[ImageData[ColorQuantize[Image[data], 3]]]];
quan /. Thread[Sort[tal[[All, 1]]] -> Range[Length[tal]]]
```

The final line sorts the values, and replaces the numbers with integers, as requested in the comment.

Comment: Ok, that is an idea. The main issue I see is that I need the values to be equally separated, like 1, 2, 3, 4 ... where the values in 1 are less than the values in 2, etc. The ColorQuantize function seems to generate random numbers, like "0.125955".

Comment: Then why not assign each of the "random" numbers to an integer? I've updated the answer.